# display image from resource folder on facebook wall in android

Tags: android

I am trying to post an image from my Resource folder onto facebook wall. everything is working perfectly. If i use a URL of an image, it gets posted on my facebook wall. What i want to know is how do i ost an image from my resource folder to facebook wall. here is a snippet of my code. any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    Context ctx = null;
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),R.drawable.bestbuy_deal);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();
    params.putString("name","ICE App");
    params.putString("caption", "Bestbuy Deal for SONY Action Cam");
    params.putString("description", "Checkout SONY ICE For exciting deals!!");
    params.putString("link", "http://www.sony.com");
    params.putByteArray("picture", bitMapData);
//  params.putString("picture", "R.drawable.sony");

    facebook.dialog(this, "me/feed",params, new DialogListener()
```

Comment: i am editing it.. i am new to Stackoverflow..

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Facebook API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), the "picture" parameter must be a URL to the picture, not an array of bytes. I imagine this is because the facebook dialog is using a `WebView` to display the feed post, and the image must therefore be available on the web.

You could try using a [local resource URI](http://androidbook.blogspot.com/2009/08/referring-to-android-resources-using.html), but this may not work completely since the Facebook API will need to be smart enough to pull that data from the local URI and put it up on their own servers. I'd be keen to know if it works, though!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I followed the local resource URI link. It deals with video. Also the link does not show how the person has posted that video on facebook.. so i am not sure how do i go about it..

Comment: Right, I was just suggesting you follow the pattern for local resource URIs described in that post. So in your case you might try passing something like "android.resource://com.your.package.here/drawable/bestbuy_deal" as the value for the "picture" parameter.